# Alternating background color in HTML UL 

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like to alternate the background color in a HTML un-ordered list *without* using JQuery.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why with JavaScript? If you generate the list dynamically, you can easily do this without JavaScript.

Comment: I just wanted to do this using javascript dynamically!

Comment: please ask your questions with a little bit more details i'm missing your 'point'

Comment: If you want a JS-only solution don't tag it CSS.

Comment: I've edited your question a bit, but it still needs more information. Try explaining _why_ you have to do it with JS (people will naturally think "why not just do that with (php/python/ruby/c#/whatever)) and try to explain what you've tried. You've articulated your desired end result, but we're having a very difficult time figuring out your _problem_.

Comment: I knew how to do it with jQuery. But I was just thinking why not use small script to do this. Though i can do this with PHP, I am not creating a dynamic server side website.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Best option would be CSS3 `:nth-child` selector:

```
#myul li:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: red;
}
#myul li:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: green;
}
```

or if for some reason you really need javascript solution:

```
<style>
    li.even { background-color: red; }
    li.odd { background-color: blue; }
</style>

var ul = document.getElementById('myul');
var items = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    var class = i % 2 == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd';
    items[i].className = class;
}
```

or as already mentioned you could just generate the classes server-side.

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
.uneven{background-color:red;}
.even{background-color:green;}
</style>
<ul>
<li class="uneven">A</li>
<li class="even">B</li>
<li class="uneven">C</li>
<li class="even">D</li>
</ul>
```

Missing the point probably..

Comment: I said just javascript dynamically!

Comment: Then why did you tag it 'css'?

Comment: because i must use CSS using javascript: foo.style.backgroundColor="#cccccc";

Comment: @HTweaks yeah it was a VERY clear question, how could I be so dumb... #hatelisted

Comment: @HTweaks: You realize browsers have their own implementations of CSS that don't require JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with just CSS:
http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-child-pseudo

This won't work in IE, though.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do it on all UL's in the page without any CSS - http://jsfiddle.net/2G7wx/1/